# How to install dotnet core onto Windows Server Nano Docker image

Tags: dockerfile

I'm using the following:

Docker for Windows (1.13.0-beta38 (9805))
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio Code (v1.8.1)

I want to create a dockerfile from the `microsoft/nanoserver` base image.
From there I want to install the software I need for my app.

For the moment let's say I want to install the following:

- dotnet core runtime
- asp.net core framework

Can someone show me what I would need to add to the below Dockerfile to achieve this please?

I've been to the [.NET Core CLI](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) site but I can only see a way to download an installer, not an option to install via the command line.

Thanks

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
*** commands that install the software I need ***
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's currently impossible to get dotnet core or asp.net core working with nanoserver on Docker.  There's a NanoServerPackage, but it's for creating a VM and appears to be [incompatible with Docker](https://github.com/OneGet/NanoServerPackage/issues/12).  I can't even get a [simple Kestrel deployment](http://serverfault.com/questions/835502/app-returns-no-error-message-running-kestrel-on-nanoserver-in-docker-missing-dl) working.  I think you need to use the massive 5 Gig Windows 2016 Server images, or else switch to a linux-based image like  `microsoft/aspnetcore`.

Comment: .. and even if you do get it to work, there's a [showstopper bug in WinNAT](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/181#issuecomment-252671828) which prevents a dockerized windows image from working on localhost.  (This bug is at least a year old.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use powershell install script for .net core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

Something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver:10.0.14393.2551
COPY install install
WORKDIR c:/install
RUN ["powershell", "./dotnet-install.ps1"]
```

(.ps1 script was in my "install" folder... )